# How to add data step by step in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I want to implement this adding by **kotlin language**. In steps:

1. For each data needs to add, the user clicks on `+Add other deposit`, represent the first area to allow add a new data, and `+Add other deposit` button goes to down.
2. And add feature if the user wants to cancel this adding, he just click on `×` button to cancel and the `+Add other deposit` button return to up again.
3. The entered data in `EditText` and selected choice in `RadioButton` to be hold in a variable and submit it by `FloatingActionButton` blew left .

**Thanks so much for your efforts in advance**
[image: Implement data in steps]

Comment: Guys. Do you wanna post kotlin codes I did and tag codes for my own trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done with create a list and when you click on the +Add other deposit button you add a new item to the list using recyclerview adapter. One problem with the input fields, i save information when the user presses on the keyboard the done button, it is also possible to save data from the field when the focus is lost, decided that it is better to save after pressing.

```
package com.myply.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnAddOtherDeposit = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.btn_add_other_deposit)
        val rvCustomers = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_customers)
        val fabDone = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab_done)

        val adapter = MyRecyclerAdapter(this, arrayListOf(CustomerModel()))
        rvCustomers.adapter = adapter
        rvCustomers.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        adapter.mClickListener = object : MyRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemRemoveClicked(position: Int) {
                adapter.removeAt(position)
            }
        }
        btnAddOtherDeposit.setOnClickListener {
            /*add empty model without information */
            adapter.add(CustomerModel())
        }
        fabDone.setOnClickListener {
            /*collect all data*/
            var customers = adapter.data
        }
    }
}
```

adapter

```
package com.myply.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.RadioButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyRecyclerAdapter internal constructor(
    val context: Context?,
    val data: MutableList<CustomerModel>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_customer, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val customer = data[position]

        holder.editName.setText(customer.name)

        holder.rbDeposit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
        holder.rbCheque.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)

        holder.rbDeposit.isChecked = customer.depositType == "Deposit"
        holder.rbCheque.isChecked = customer.depositType == "Cheque"

        holder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener { mClickListener?.onItemRemoveClicked(position) }
        holder.editName.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
            override fun onEditorAction(p0: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event?.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    customer.name = holder.editName.text.toString()

                    holder.editName.clearFocus()

                    update(customer, position)
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        })
        holder.rbDeposit.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            customer.depositType = "Deposit"

            update(customer, position)
        }
        holder.rbCheque.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            customer.depositType = "Cheque"

            update(customer, position)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    fun add(customer: CustomerModel) {
        data.add(customer)
        notifyItemInserted(data.size - 1)
    }

    fun update(customer: CustomerModel, position: Int) {
        data[position] = customer
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    fun removeAt(position: Int) {
        data.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var editName: EditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_name)
        var btnRemove: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove)
        var rbDeposit: RadioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb_deposit)
        var rbCheque: RadioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb_cheque)
    }

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemRemoveClicked(position: Int)
    }
}
```

item_customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_deposit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Deposit type" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_cheque"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cheque" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_customers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_add_other_deposit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="Add other deposit" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, my tongue and typing can't describe how I thank you so much for your efforts you did to done this work by this wonderful.
But my experience not like you. There're multi points I wanna ask you about it. So, please provide to me a contact way to discuss more about those points

Comment: @MohamadMF write me in telegram if you have https://t.me/yura_yatsko